# Assigning a string to variables names

Tags: list-manipulation, variable, assignment

I have the list

```
n1 = {{REL1, "REL.csv"}, {RAND1, "RAND.csv\"}}.
```

That is `{{variable name, string}, {name, string}}`.  I want the variable `REL1` to be set to `"REL.csv"`. How can I do that?

`n1[1,1]] = n1[1,2]]` does not work.

Comment: If you want each name `Set` to the associated string use `Set @@@ n1`

Answer (score 5):

Still another approach is

```
Clear[REL1, RAND1, n1]; 
n1 = {{REL1, "REL.csv"}, {RAND1, "RAND.csv"}};
Set @@ First[n1];
```

which yields

```
{REL1, RAND1}
(* {"REL.csv", RAND1} *)
```

as expected.  To perform this process on the whole list, use

```
Clear[REL1, RAND1, n1]; 
n1 = {{REL1, "REL.csv"}, {RAND1, "RAND.csv"}};
Set @@@ n1;
```

which yields

```
{REL1, RAND1}
(* {"REL.csv", "RAND.csv"} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using replacements by replacing List with Set. For example:

```
n1 = {{REL1, "REL.csv"}, {RAND1, "RAND.csv"}};
Evaluate[n1[[1]] /. List -> Set]
```

Now REL1 is REL.csv

You can do a whole list of such things:

```
Clear[REL1, RAND1];
n1 = {{REL1, "REL.csv"}, {RAND1, "RAND.csv"}};
Table[Evaluate[n1[[i]]] /. List -> Set, {i, Length[n1]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[REL1, RAND1];
n1 = {{REL1, "REL.csv"}, {RAND1, "RAND.csv"}};
(Evaluate@First@# = Last@#) & /@ n1;
{REL1, RAND1}
(* {"REL.csv", "RAND.csv"} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Applying set at level 1

n1 = {{REL1, "REL.csv"}, {RAND1, "RAND.csv"}};

(#1 = #2) & @@@ n1;

{REL1, RAND1}

> ```
> {"REL.csv", "RAND.csv"}
> ```